# Why use regularization?

Tags: regression, machine-learning-model, overfitting, regularization

In a linear model, regularization decreases the slope. Do we just assume that fitting a lin model on training data overfits by almost always creating a slope which is higher than it would be with infinite observations instead? What is the intuition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regularization is used to help smooth multi-dimensional models.
Take this example,

```
y = x_1 + eps*(x_2 + ... + x_100)
```

Let's say eps is very small. It  doesnt seem very useful to store those 99 coefficients, isn't it? How do we manage to fit a model in such a way that we drop negligible coefficients? This is exactly what L1-regularisation does!

Each other type of regularisation has another geometric intuition.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So it seems like there is no fundamental use in applying regularization to a simple linear regression model with only one variable(Except of-course if you have an optimization problem like in the real world). Your explanation makes lots of sense to me.